# Smooth streaming player with Silverlight, is it possible to set the mediaurl to relative path?

Tags: silverlight, media-url, smooth-streaming-player

Here is my code

```
 <div id="silverlightControlHost">
                    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="70%" height="70%">
                    <param name="source" value="Video/SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap"/>
                    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                    <param name="background" value="white" />
                    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
                    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                        <param name="InitParams" value="selectedcaptionstream=textstream_eng,mediaurl=http://servername/Video/video.ssm/manifest" />
                      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
                        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
                      </a>
                    </object>
                    </div>
```

Question:
Is it possible to have mediaurl attribute set to a relative path? 
So instead of

http://servername/Video/video.ssm/manifest

It would be something like

/Video/video.ssm/manifest

I tried it as is, but it errored out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the media must be served directly via IIS